# Need help selecting proper columns for output in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
select  
    p.ProductID, max(hist.Cost) as 'MaxPrice'
from
    Product as p, ProductCostHistory as hist
where   
    p.ProductID = hist.ProductID
group by    
    p.ProductID
```

What I have is a SQL query meant to get a product and the highest price it ever was. The issue though is that my first column is the product's ID (p.ProductID), and I want the first column to be the product's name (p.name). I can't simply group by product name because some products have different IDs despite having the same name.

The query above gives me the correct output as far as I can tell, how would I retrieve the name instead of the ID?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may `GROUP BY` the combination of `ProductID` and `name`:

```
SELECT
    p.ProductID,
    p.name,
    MAX(hist.Cost) AS 'MaxPrice'
FROM Product AS p
INNER JOIN ProductCostHistory AS hist
    ON p.ProductID = hist.ProductID
GROUP BY
    p.ProductID,
    p.name;
```

This combination should still be unique, because a given `ProductID` should ideally only ever map to a single name.

If you really wanted to display only the `name` and max price, then you could subquery the above answer and select only `name` and `MaxPrice`.  But, this might result in multiple records for a given name, and you would then have no way to separate one from the other.

Side note: Try to use explicit join syntax if possible, unless there is compelling reason otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sub query and INNER JOIN with same table to get your requirement as-

```
select p.name,temp_prod.ProductID,temp_prod.cost as highes_cost from Product 
INNER JOIN (
       select  
          p.ProductID, max(hist.Cost) as cost as 'MaxPrice'
       from
          Product as p, ProductCostHistory as hist
       where   
          p.ProductID = hist.ProductID
       group by    
          p.ProductID
          )temp_prod ON
( temp_prod.ProductID = Product.ProductID )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
SELECT p.ProductId, 
    p.Name, 
    (SELECT MAX(cost) FROM ProductCostHistory as hist where p.ProductID = hist.ProductID)
FROM Product as p
```

or

```
SELECT p.ProductId, t2.cost, p.Name
FROM Product as p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT productId, MAX(cost) FROM ProductCostHistory 
      group by ProductId) t2
    ON p.ProductId = t2.Productid
```